# MongoDB Compass JSON Document Failed Validation

Tags: mongodb, json

Apologies in advance if I am asking this question in the wrong place. I have read a number of similar questions and responses on this topic but many seem outdated and don't seem to fit my issues.

I am trying to add my first data to a collection and continually get the error "Failed to import with the following error: Document failed validation" in Compass. I have checked the schema and data and don't see an issue.

My schema in MongoDB is as follows

```
{ $jsonSchema: {
bsonType: 'object',
required: [
  'firstName',
  'lastName',
  'email',
  'phoneNumber',
  'password',
  'dateOfBirth',
  'gender',
  'primaryAddress'
],
properties: {
  firstName: {
    bsonType: 'string',
    description: 'First name of the user'
  },
  lastName: {
    bsonType: 'string',
    description: 'Last name of the user'
  },
  email: {
    bsonType: 'string',
    description: 'Email address of the user'
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    bsonType: 'string',
    description: 'Phone number of the user'
  },
  password: {
    bsonType: 'string',
    description: 'Password for the user\'s account'
  },
  dateOfBirth: {
    bsonType: 'date',
    description: 'Date of birth of the user'
  },
  gender: {
    bsonType: 'string',
    description: 'Gender of the user'
  },
  primaryAddress: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    required: [
      'streetAddress',
      'city',
      'state',
      'zipCode',
      'country'
    ],
    properties: {
      streetAddress: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'Street address of the user\'s primary address'
      },
      city: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'City of the user\'s primary address'
      },
      state: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'State of the user\'s primary address'
      },
      zipCode: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'Zip code of the user\'s primary address'
      },
      country: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'Country of the user\'s primary address'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the data I am using is

```
{ "firstName": "Trot", 
"lastName": "Nixon",
"email": "trot.nixon@example.com",
"phoneNumber": "555-123-4567",
"password": "mySecurePassword123",
"dateOfBirth": "1974-04-11",
"gender": "male",
"primaryAddress": {
"streetAddress": "123 Main St",
"city": "Boston",
"state": "MA",
  "zipCode": "02101",
  "country": "USA"
}
}
```

I am running MongoDB Compass 1.36.2, my cluster is Shared and version 5.0.15.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.